# AJAX with casperJS to determine fail from returned text and send email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

*QUESTION:*
What I would like to do is have an email go out every time CasperJS AJAX comes back with a Fail of 1 or greater, such as `Fail: 1 ["user666name"]`. Is there a way to fetch a portion of the returned AJAX text, and based on that log it as a `Fail` and then send an email notification about this failure?

*EXPLANATION:*
I am using CasperJS to log in multiple users into a page, and the final echo from this script returns the amount of successful log-ins and failed log-ins, based on correct usernames/passwords, and it looks like this:

> Test Results: Success: 3 ["username1","username2","username3"] Fail: 1 ["user666name"]

I am using AJAX to call the this CasperJS script from a PHP file when echoes back the CasperJS echoed results. I have it set to run every 30 minutes using `setTimeout` And the way I have my AJAX set up loads this in my page where the request originated:

> Test Results: Success: 3 ["username1","username2","username3"] Fail: 1 ["user666name"]
>
> Test completed in 62189 ms, on Sat Jul 26 2014 12:58:34 GMT-0400 (EDT)

This is my PHP page with the AJAX:

```
<div id="mainContent">
<p>Welcome to the CasperJS Automated Testing Utility</p>
  <button id="button_AJAX">Run casperJS</button>
  <button id="button_STOP" onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop casperJS</button>
</div>
<div id="loading"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#button_AJAX').click(function doStuff() {
        // add loading image to div
       $('#loading').html('<img src="rays.gif"><br><i>Web harvesting in progress; please wait for test results.</i>');
            var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        // Run ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            url: "phpwithCasperJS.php",
                // AJAX success
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#loading').html(data);
                    // Total time and date / time of AJAX completion
                    var totalTime = new Date().getTime()-ajaxTime;
                    window.alert = function(message) {
                        var output = document.getElementById('loading'),
                            newTextContainer = document.createElement('p'),
                            text = document.createTextNode(message);
                        newTextContainer.appendChild(text);
                        output.appendChild(newTextContainer);
                        if(dd<10) {
                        dd='0'+dd
                        } 
                        if(mm<10) {
                            mm='0'+mm
                        } 
                        today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;         
                    }
                    alert("Test completed in " + totalTime + " ms, on " + today);
            }   
        }); 
    timeout = setTimeout(doStuff,3000000);  });
    $("#button_AJAX").click(function() {$("#button_AJAX").text("CasperJS Executed");});
    $("#button_STOP").click(function() {$("#button_AJAX").text("Run casperJS");});
    function myStopFunction() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
</script>
```

The PHP housing the casperJS script:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><p style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #000000">Test Results: </p></td>
  <td><?php
    echo exec("/usr/local/bin/casperjs /path/to/script/casperJSscript.js");
?></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't send the email in your browser, let PHP do that in `phpwithCasperJS.php`. Also, you have a lot of unnecessary description about your setup.

Comment: Hi. I posted my PHP file that is being requested by AJAX, it only contains the casperJS execution of its script. How could I send them email before it returns the AJAX text to the requesting page? Only then, can I determine if **Fail: (is greater than 1)**. Correct?

Comment: Once the AJAX text returns, I can use something like: 

`if(data.indexOf("Fail: 1 *not sure how to set it up to be >=1") > -1)
{           
//Send email
}`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thank you for the link. But how can I only execute this if the returned AJAX string contains **"Fail: (a number of 1 or greater)"**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Should I find the text element in the PHP page containing the execution of casperJS script or in the page requesting the AJAX? I am trying to find **Fail: 1** from the PHP echo using ob_get_contents(); but it is not working.

Comment: I am stuck and I do not know how to search for a **Fail** of value **1 or greater**. I can only search for **Fail: 1**. How do I check for 1 or more **>=1**? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `phpwithCasperJS.php` where you execute the CasperJS script, you need to look at the output returned from the command and based on that send the e-mail:

```
<?php
    $output = exec("/usr/local/bin/casperjs /path/to/script/casperJSscript.js");
    if (strpos($output, 'Fail: 0') === FALSE) {
        mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

You might want to send the e-mail via <kbd>[Mail_smtp](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/docs/1.2.0/Mail/Mail_smtp.html)</kbd>, if your server is blocked by spamhaus.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! I have never sent an email using PHP, so please bare with me. Do I fill the mail line like this:

**mail($to = 'username@mail.com', $subject = 'My Subject', $message = 'My Message.');**

Comment: No, this would be `mail('username@mail.com', 'My Subject', 'My Message.');`

Comment: And I'm assuming I have to use and configure something like PHPMailer for Gmail, and edit my php.ini to enable openssl.dll ?

Comment: Yes, PHPMailer is an alternative to `Mail_smtp` which I linked. Good think, that there are [complete examples](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail) for that.

Comment: Would you happen to know why PHP only allows me to echo the last echo found within my casperJS script? I have many **this.echo** in casperJS but only the last one is shown in PHP, and additionally none of my **this.capture** work.

Comment: Please, read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). It clearly states that only the last line is returned. You would need to pass an array as a second argument to exec to populate it with all the output lines.

Comment: I used `passthru()` and `system()` and you are right these do return all the `this.echo` from within the CasperJS script, although, unfortunately all in 1 line, instead of separate lines as it appears in the shell. But regardless, neither one of these allows the `this.capture` from the script to write the **.PNG** file. Is this an issue with 0777 permissions? The way my script is setup: `this.capture('Success_'+username+'.png');` will cause the image to have a unique name given the username, so how I have the PHP write a file that does not exist yet? Is this even possible?